# Firefox addon: Set as HomePage NewTab checkboxes at options window

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, add-on

I would like to make firefox addon that change default New Page and Start Page to specific page. I'm trying to do an Options window with checkboxes to enable or disable settings, but they won't work. Please help me.

**preferences.xul:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<prefwindow xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <prefpane id="mystartpage-options" label="Opcje">
        <preferences>
            <preference id="extensions.mystartpage.overrideHomePage" name="extensions.mystartpage.overrideHomePage" type="bool"/>
            <preference id="extensions.mystartpage.overrideNewTab" name="extensions.mystartpage.overrideNewTab" type="bool"/>
        </preferences>
        <checkbox id="useAsHomePage" label="Strona startowa" preference="extensions.mystartpage.overrideHomePage"/>
        <checkbox id="openInNewTabs" label="Nowa karta" preference="extensions.mystartpage.overrideNewTab"/>
    </prefpane>
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="preferences.js"/>
</prefwindow>
```

**preferences.js:**

```js
mystartpageoptions = new function () {
    var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService).getBranch("accessibility.");
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

    if ((Services.prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.mystartpage.overrideNewTab")) = true)
        Services.prefs.setCharPref("browser.newtab.url", "chrome://mystartpage/content/index.html")
    else Services.prefs.clearUserPref("browser.newtab.url");

    if ((Services.prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.mystartpage.overrideHomePage")) = true)
        Services.prefs.setCharPref("browser.startup.homepage", "chrome://mystartpage/content/index.html")
    else Services.prefs.clearUserPref("browser.startup.homepage");
}
```

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: To change new tab and start page using checkboxes in addon's options window. Firefox still loads default start page and new tab page.